# JPA persist fails with new compound key existing relation entities

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm using:

- Spring framework version: 3.2.2.RELEASE
- hibernate version: 4.3.0.CR1
- spring-data-jpa: 1.3.1.RELEASE

I have following classes:

- Client
- ClientInfo
- Service

Each Client can have [0, N] ClientInfos (one-to-many). Each ClientInfo can have [0, N] Services. And for each ClientInfo-Service 'joint' I have an extra 'description' -field to describe the relationship. The 'joint'-class is called:

- ClientInfoService

An example of resulting data structure:

- Client

  - ClientInfo

    - ClientInfoService

      - Service
      - Description
    - ClientInfoService

      - Service
      - Description
    - ClientInfoService

      - Service
      - Description

Here are the codes for the classes:

```
@Entity
public class Client {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "client", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<ClientInfo> infos = new HashSet<ClientInfo>();

    public Set<ClientInfo> getInfos() {
        return infos;
    }

    public void setInfos(Set<ClientInfo> infos) {
        this.infos.clear();
        this.infos.addAll(infos);
        for (Iterator<ClientInfo> iterator = infos.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            ClientInfo item = iterator.next();

            // update client relation to ClientInfo item because it is not necessarily up-to-date with the given input data
            item.setClient(this);
        }
    }
}

@Entity
public class ClientInfo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    ...

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "client_id", nullable = false)
    private Client client;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "clientInfoService.client", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<ClientInfoService> services = new HashSet<ClientInfoService>();

    public Set<ClientInfoService> getServices() {
        return services;
    }

    public void setServices(Set<ClientInfoService> services) {
        this.services.clear();
        this.services.addAll(services);
        for (Iterator<ClientInfoService> iterator = services.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            ClientInfoService item = iterator.next();
            // update client info relation to ClientInfoService item because it is not necessarily up-to-date with the given input data
            item.getClientInfoService().setClientInfo(this);
        }
    }
}

@Entity
public class Service {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "clientInfoService.service", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<ClientInfoService> infoServices = new HashSet<ClientInfoService>();

    @JsonIgnore
    public Set<ClientInfoService> getInfoServices() {
        return infoServices;
    }

    public void setInfoServices(Set<ClientInfoService> infoServices) {
        this.infoServices.clear();
        this.infoServices.addAll(infoServices);
        for (Iterator<ClientInfoService> iterator = infoServices.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            ClientInfoService item = iterator.next();
            // update service relation to ClientInfoService item because it is not necessarily up-to-date with the given input data
            item.getClientInfoService().setService(this);
        }
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "clientInfo_service")
public class ClientInfoService {

    @EmbeddedId
    private ClientInfoServiceAssociationId clientInfoService;

    @Column(name = "description", nullable = true, length = 200)
    private String description;

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public ClientInfoServiceAssociationId getClientInfoService() {
        return clientInfoService;
    }
    public void setClientInfoService(ClientInfoServiceAssociationId clientInfoService) {
        this.clientInfoService = clientInfoService;
    }


    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
    if (this.clientInfoService != null) {
        return this.clientInfoService.hashCode();
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

@Embeddable
public class ClientInfoServiceAssociationId implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "clientInfo_id", nullable = false)
    private ClientInfo clientInfo;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "service_id", nullable = false)
    private Service service;

    @JsonIgnore
    public ClientInfo getClientInfo() {
        return clientInfo;
    }

    public void setClientInfo(ClientInfo clientInfo) {
        this.clientInfo = clientInfo;
    }

    public Service getService() {
        return service;
    }

    public void setService(Service service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        ClientInfoServiceAssociationId id = (ClientInfoServiceAssociationId) obj;
        boolean cond = false;
        boolean serv = false;
        if (id.clientInfo != null && this.clientInfo != null && id.clientInfo.getId() == this.clientInfo.getId()) {
            cond = true;
        }
        if (id.service != null && this.service != null && id.service.getId() == this.service.getId()) {
            serv = true;
        }
        return cond && serv;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int ret = 0;
        if (this.clientInfo != null && this.clientInfo.getId() != null) {
            ret += this.clientInfo.getId();
        }
        if (this.service != null) {
            ret += this.service.getId();
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Everything works perfectly when saving clients with new infos without existing services. The problem case with this setup is:

**Save client data with a new info (id: null) with links to existing services.**


Following exception comes when calling saveAndFlush():

```
WARN : org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: -177, SQLState: 23503
ERROR: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - integrity constraint violation: foreign key no parent; FK_L5435O51W7YGX5N3NEJ84GN9V table: CLIENTINFO_SERVICE
ERROR: fi.loikka.nursebuddy.controller.GlobalControllerExceptionHandler - GENERAL ERROR!
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:321)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:403)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:58)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor$LockModePopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy90.saveAndFlush(Unknown Source)
     at fi.myCompany.component.update(ClientServiceImpl.java:130)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy92.update(Unknown Source)
    at fi.myCompany.component2.updateClient(ClientController.java:107)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:849)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:691)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:66)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:168)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at fi.myCompany.security.TokenFilter.doFilterInternal(TokenFilter.java:66)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:134)
    at fi.myCompany.component.Test.addClientInfoWithService(ClientControllerTest.java:426)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:264)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray2(ReflectionUtils.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:87)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.InPluginVMSurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcess(InPluginVMSurefireStarter.java:83)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:793)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:703)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:631)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1770)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1684)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1690)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1345)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:241)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy76.flush(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.flush(SimpleJpaRepository.java:397)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.saveAndFlush(SimpleJpaRepository.java:365)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:333)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:318)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155)
    ... 125 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:190)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3123)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3586)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:453)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:345)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1167)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1342)
    ... 145 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: integrity constraint violation: foreign key no parent; FK_L5435O51W7YGX5N3NEJ84GN9V table: CLIENTINFO_SERVICE
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:187)
    ... 155 more
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: integrity constraint violation: foreign key no parent; FK_L5435O51W7YGX5N3NEJ84GN9V table: CLIENTINFO_SERVICE
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Constraint.getException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Constraint.checkInsert(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementDML.performIntegrityChecks(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementDML.insertSingleRow(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementInsert.getResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementDMQL.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.executeCompiledStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
    ... 158 more
```

Test case

```
@Test
@DatabaseSetup(value = "clientcontroller/clientcontrollertestdata_client_with_infos.xml", type = DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT)
@ExpectedDatabase(value = "clientcontroller/clientcontrollertestdata_client_add_infos_after.xml", assertionMode = DatabaseAssertionMode.NON_STRICT)
public void addClientInfoWithService() throws Exception {
    datasource.getConnection().prepareStatement("SET DATABASE REFERENTIAL INTEGRITY TRUE").execute();

    Client client = createTestClient( ...);

    HashSet<ClientInfo> infos = new HashSet<ClientInfo>();

    ClientInfo info1 = new ClientInfo( … );
    info1.setId(1l);

    Service service1 = new Service( … );
    service1.setId(1l);

    ClientInfo info2 = new ClientInfo( … );

    ClientInfoServiceAssociationId compoundKey = new ClientInfoServiceAssociationId();
    compoundKey.setClientInfo(info2);
    compoundKey.setService(service1);

    ClientInfoService clientInfoNew = new ClientInfoService();
    clientInfoNew.setDescription("new description");
    clientInfoNew.setClientInfoService(compoundKey);

    HashSet<ClientInfoService> set = new HashSet<ClientInfoService>();
    set.add(clientInfoNew);
    info2.setServices(set);

    service1.setInfoServices(set);

    infos.add(info1);
    infos.add(info2);

    client.setInfos(infos);

    String resultJSON = jsonConverter.convertToJSON(client);

    mockMvc.perform(put("/clients/1").header("headertoken", this.token).content(resultJSON).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andExpect(
            status().isNoContent());
}
```

What could be the problem? Something in my entity definions?

Comment: Post the full stacktrace.

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of your schema?

Comment: @gregor, I'm sorry but I'm new to this, so I have to ask: in what format you want me to post my database schema? Is there not enough information depicted in the entity classes (tables, column names, datatypes, relations etc)?

Comment: @M.Deinum, I added full stacktrace.

Comment: @anterosalonen It looks like you don't set an assoziation that your schema does require. Hence the foreign key constraint `FK_L5435O51W7YGX5N3NEJ84GN9V` on the table CLIENTINFO_SERVICE fails. An without knowing what `FK_???` is it is hard to tell you something on the problem.

Comment: @gregor From the schema I see that foreign key FK_L5435O51W7YGX5N3NEJ84GN9V points to clientInfo_id column in the ClientInfoServiceAssociationId entity. And the clientInfo object it points to is the one object _not_ existing in the database prior to  performing this failing save-operation. I added the test case code for you to see.

Comment: @gregor Could it be that when sending the json data in my test case, the associated ClientInfo is ignored (with @JsonIgnore) and therefore missing from the data going to the server. And because in the beginning of the test case I set the database integrity to true, this link is missing?